# C: AVL tree search method for a certain value

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, avl-tree

I'm trying to write a function that searches in an AVL tree after a certain value and returns how many nodes contain the searched value.

Here it's my struct :

```
struct building{
int id;
char* streetName;
int streetNumber; };
```

And this is my search function :

```
void searchAfterStreetName(node* root, char* searchedStreet){
int counter = 0;
if (root){
    if (strcmp(searchedStreet, root->info->streetName) < 0){
        return searchAfterStreetName(root->left, searchedStreet);
    }
    else if (strcmp(searchedStreet, root->info->streetName) > 0){
        return searchAfterStreetName(root->right, searchedStreet);
    }
    else{
        if (strcmp(searchedStreet, root->info->streetName) == 0){
                counter = counter + 1;
                printf("%d\n", counter);
            }

        }
      }
else{
    printf("Not found");
}

}
```

Basically, what I want to do is to perform a search in an AVL Tree after the street name and everytime the searched value is contained in a node I will increment  the value of the counter and print out the total value at the end of the search on the console.
 The search function works well until I add the counter. It enters in an infinite loop. Please help !!!

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example? I don't see why this would enter an infinite loop.

Comment: Does that compile?  You've a function returning `void` but you have `return searchAfterStreetName(…);` in the body, which is not valid C (but it might be allowed in C++ — are you using a C++ compiler in disguise, such as MSVC?).

Comment: Note that each separate invocation of `searchAfterStreetName()` has its own copy of `counter`.  Its value will never get to be more than 1.  The `if` test in the `else` clause is redundant too; the only way that code can be executed is if the condition will be true. You could flatten the 'bushy tree' of `if`s by using `if (root == 0) printf("Not found\n");` first; then you'd have the `else if (strcmp(…) > 0)` etc. Also note that repeating `strcmp()` is not ideal; it isn't a particularly cheap function — though there are many more expensive ones.  `int cmp;` … `else if ((cmp = strcmp(…)) > 0)`.

Comment: Hmmm...GCC 5.3.0 requires prodding with `-pedantic` before it complains `ISO C forbids ‘return’ with expression, in function returning void [-Wpedantic]`.  C++ seems to allow it even with `-pedantic`.

Comment: How is your AVL tree being set up? This will only work if it's ordered by `streetName`. If that's the case, then the function is still a bit strange in that I don't understand what's happening with the information. If a node with `searchedStreet` exists, it'll just find the first one, print "1" and stop. How do you know the function is working well before the counter?